# How do I get the position in the middle of a CSS Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm making a music website with a playhead that I've animated to move along the screen and loop back.

```
.playhead {
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 0.2em solid;
    min-height: calc(100% - var(--display-border-width));
    border-color: red;
    animation: play-animation 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes play-animation {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%
    }
}
```

Now while the playhead is moving, I want to access its position value, or how far along the screen it is (`offsetX`), so I can play the notes or whatever at that position.

So if it halfway across the screen, and the screen is 1000px wide, I want to access the 500px value during the animation.

I've tried using `useEffect` and `useRef` together, but that only gets called when the animation stops or starts, but not while it is running. So the value stays the same during the animation

I've tried setting up a seperate `setInterval` for calculating the position only, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (props.play) {
            const markers = (playTime * 1000) / frameRate;
            const percentToAdd = 100 / markers;

            const id = setInterval(() => {setProgress((prev) => (prev + percentToAdd) % 100)}, frameRate);
            setIntervalID(id);
        } else {
            if (intervalID !== 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }
    }, [props.play]);
```

But this is out of sync for some reason. And plus, I'd rather the position values come from the playhead directly.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: the greensock animation library has functionality that can do this. They have a really good support / help forum as well https://greensock.com/